# merge two rows in return query as one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I  have a query that returns the people in a certain household, however the individuals show up in to separate rows, what i want to do is merge the two rows into one.

```
SELECT     dbo.households.id, dbo.individuals.firstname, dbo.individuals.lastname
FROM         dbo.households INNER JOIN
                      dbo.individuals ON dbo.households.id = dbo.individuals.householdID
WHERE     (dbo.households.id = 10017)
```

Current results:

```
ID | First Name | Last Name |
1  | Test       | Test1     |
1  | ABC        | ABC1      |
```

Desired results:

```
ID | First Name | Last Name |ID1| First Name1| Last Name1|
1  | Test       | Test1     |1  | ABC        | ABC1      |
```

However if theres 3 people then it would need to merge all 3 and so on

Comment: how do you want the result to look?  If it's one row does it have N*3 columns for N records?

Comment: Are you wanting to `PIVOT`, that is put two rows data into one row (firstname1, lastname1, firstname2, lastname2, ...)?  If so, it will probably require dynamic SQL because you are returning a dynamic number of columns.  What are the requirements you are trying to fulfill that require you to have the data in that layout?

Comment: yeah thats what i am worried about, the number of people can change depending on households

Comment: @pst i dont see how a group by would help here

Comment: @mellamokb i think you are the closest to what im trying to do

Comment: Do you need the names to be in a separate column or can they be adjoined and separated by a delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the response to the question I asked above, below is a simple script that would compile the names into a string and then output the string (I don't have access to the syntax validator now so forgive any errors):

```
DECLARE 
    @CNT INT,
    @R_MAX INT,
    @H_ID INT,
    @R_FIRST VARCHAR(250),
    @R_LAST VARCHAR(250),
    @R_NAMES VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @CNT = 0; --Counter
SET @R_NAMES = 'Names: ';
SELECT @R_MAX = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.individuals a WHERE a.householdID = @H_ID; --Get total number of individuals
PRINT(@R_MAX); --Output # of matching rows
--Loop through table to get individuals
WHILE @CNT < @R_MAX
    BEGIN
        --Select statement
        SELECT * FROM (SELECT
            @R_FIRST = b.firstname,
            @R_LAST = b.lastname,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.lastname, b.firstname) AS Row
        FROM
            dbo.households a INNER JOIN
            dbo.individuals b ON a.id = b.householdID 
        WHERE
            (a.id = @H_ID)) AS RN WHERE (Row = @CNT);

        SET @R_NAMES = @R_NAMES + @R_FIRST + @R_LAST + '; '; --Add individual's name to name string
              PRINT(CAST(@CNT AS VARCHAR) + ':' + @R_NAMES);
        SET @CNT = @CNT +1; --Increase counter
    END

PRINT(@R_NAMES); --Output the individuals
```

Comment: didnt realize it was so complicated i thought maybe i could have done a for each row type of thing but it wasnt working

Comment: This isn't the only method, but this would be how I would handle it.  I would actually throw it into a stored procedure to help with portability and pass the @R_ID as a paramater to the stored procedure.  You could then even setup a loop that looped through every household id.

Comment: they can be in the same column but im having a hard time implementing this in a stored procedure. would r_id be the same as household id or is it the row id

Comment: It would be the same as household id, you can rename it to make it easier for your purposes.

Comment: I edited the code to reflect a "clearer" variable and corrected the householdID variable in the individuals table.

Comment: where the string adds the next first and last

Comment: weird 1 row is affected but it just returns 0

Comment: Updated. Does PRINT(@R_MAX) show anything?  Also, are you looking at the query results window or the messages window?  This method will output the results in the messages window.

Comment: but @r_names doesnt print in message. r_max prints in messages

Comment: Updated...Try again. If it doesn't output anything then that means that the query was unsuccessful.

Comment: it returns 4 for the max in messages and still nothing for names

Comment: ill try and play with the query its running, and for some reason i couldnt declare varchar(max) so i used varchar(250) could that be why

Comment: when i just try and PRINT('The names are: '); it shows the name are:

Comment: Try with PRINT(CAST(@CNT AS VARCHAR) + ':' + @R_NAMES); added now.

Comment: its not working but i feel bad asking u for anymore help thanks for everything

Comment: @bugz let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2178/discussion-between-robb-and-bugz)

Answer (score 1):

Provided you're using SQL Server 2005 or up, you might be able to use FOR XML PATH('') to concatenate the strings.

This should do what you want without having to do manual loops:
edit: fixed up SQL to actually work (now I have access to SQL)

```
SELECT households.id, 
  STUFF(
    (
      SELECT '; ' + [firstname] + '|' + lastname AS [text()]
      FROM individuals
      WHERE individuals.householdID = households.id
      FOR XML PATH('')
    )
    , 1, 2, '' ) -- remove the first '; ' from the string
  AS [name]
FROM dbo.households
WHERE (households.id = 10017)
```

This is pretty close to the format of data that you wanted.

it converts the data to XML (without any actual XML markup due to the PATH('')) and then joins it back to the header row.

Comment: how does the for xml path work
thanks for the info this would be a interesting method